# JsonParse Error in iPhone device but correct in simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift, xcode

This is my code:

```
    let res = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.mutableContainers) as! [[String:Any]]
```

The data is the result of Response.data.

It works well in simulator, but when in iphone6 the console outputs

```
    Could not cast value of type ‘__NSDictionaryM’ to ‘NSArray’
```

The json data format is like

```
    [{"":""},{"":""},{"":""}]
```

The jsondata form server works well for android, ios simulator. But when it comes to my iPhone device, the code fails.
the result of response json data is just {}, it's empty, but on Xcode simulator it goes well.

Can any one tell me why?

Comment: try this if it is not array  :     let res = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will be helpful:  `as! Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>`

If your format like this  `[{"":""},{"":""},{"":""}]`

Comment: Thank you for your help! But it did not work in iPhone, the Xcode simulator still goes well . The data of response is just {} in device, while it is [{"":""},{"":""},{"":""}] in simulator ,even the GET result in browser is right

Comment: Try to print the response with type casting "Any"

Answer (score 0):

check if the JSON is a real array. 
BTW, do not force unwrapping the data or jsonObject